# Create a Tuple from 2 Lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, c#-8.0, c#-7.0

I have 2 lists below:
// From Below List I want to retrieve it Text of each plan like: `foreach(var plan in AvailablePlanNames) and then use plan.Text property.`

```
private IList<IWebElement> AvailablePlanNames =>
            _webDriver.FindElementsWithWait(By.XPath("//div[@class='asc-checkbox-group']"));
```

//  From Below list I am going to pull 2 properties like:

```
foreach(var planDetail in PlanDetails), fetch:
planDetail.GetAttribute("id") and planDetail.GetAttribute("checked")

private IList<IWebElement> PlansDetails => _webDriver.FindElementsWithWait(By.XPath("//div[@class='asc-checkbox-group']/input"));
```

So first list has: `["Plan A", "Plan B", "Plan C"]`
Second list can be: `[[Plan A ID , true], [Plan B ID, false], [Plan C ID, null]]`

I am trying to make a single list of it like Tuple which will have:

```
Tuple((Plan A, Plan A ID, true), (Plan B, Plan B ID, false), (Plan C, Plan C ID, null))
```

I searched several posts and tried multiple solutions but did not get it working.

```
    public IList<string> GetAvailablePlans()
    {
        var list = new List<(string Text, string, string)>();

        foreach (var planName in AvailablePlanNames)
        {
            foreach (var planDetail in PlansDetails)
            {
                
                list.Add((planName.Text, 
                    planDetail.GetAttribute("id"), 
                    planDetail.GetAttribute("checked")));
            }

        }
        return (IList<string>)list;
    }
```

Comment: if `PlansDetails[i]` is corresponding to the `planName[i]` for specified `i`, then you need only one for-loop.

Comment: @born2Learn Is the question really, I want to transform 2 lists of values into one list of tuples. That's the question the accepted answer, answers, but it's not how you phrased the question. In which case I suggest we modify it to reflect the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? This code assumes that `PlansDetails[i]` is corresponding to the `AvailablePlanNames[i]` for specified `i`. If this is not true, you will also need to find corresponding data in `PlansDetails` for each `AvailablePlanNames[i]`.
The code also use correct return value (list of tuples instead of list of strings).

```
public List<(string Text, string, bool)> GetAvailablePlans()
{
    var list = new List<(string Text, string, string)>();

    for (var i; i<AvailablePlanNames.Length;i++)
    {
            list.Add((AvailablePlanNames[i].Text, 
                PlansDetails[i].GetAttribute("id"), 
                PlansDetails[i].GetAttribute("checked")));
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This helped me. It solved my problem. Thank you @serg.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, you can use LINQ's [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) to combine items from two `IEnumerable<T>`s.  :

```
var results=AvailablePlanNames
                .Zip(PlanDetails)
                .Select((first,second)=>
                           ( Text: first.Text,
                             Id:   second.GetAttribute("id"),
                             Check:second.GetAttrbute("checked")
                           ))
                .ToList();
```